# How can I update my Java program to only show two decimal places

Tags: java, file-io, keyboard, decimal, rounding

The class assignment is basically to have a dialog box that asks the user for employee name, hourly pay, and hours for the week.  It outputs it to a text file.  I completed that part and the teacher said he was find that the output had 4 decimal places, ex. 34.5500

I'm here to ask for assistance on how I can only show two decimal spots so its 34.55.  Here is the code I complied.

```
package out.put.of.a.file;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OutPutOfAFile
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    OutputFile payFile;
    payFile = new OutputFile("payroll.txt");
    String name;
    Double pay, hours;
    String answer;
    Keyboard k;
    k = new Keyboard();

    do
    {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the employee's name:");

        pay = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the employee's hourly wage:"));

        hours = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the employee's total hours:"));

        payFile.writeString(name);
        payFile.writeDouble(pay);
        payFile.writeDouble(hours);
        payFile.writeEOL();

        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you have another employee to enter? (yes/no)");

    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

    payFile.close();
 }

}
```

Comment: You could do some research in `NumberFormat`...

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the `printf` function. You can use percent modifiers for padding the code. It supports integers (%d) floats (%f) characters (%c) and strings (%s). All can be formatted to your liking.

`System.out.printf("%.2f", floatVariable);`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you might use a [`NumberFormat.format(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) like

```
NumberFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
payFile.writeString(name);
payFile.writeString(fmt.format(pay));
payFile.writeString(fmt.format(hours));
```

Alternatively, you could use something like `String.format("%.2f", pay);`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to import anything: [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Usage example:

```
String.format("%.2f", number);
```